# C# Sqlite function across applications

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

Is it possible to register a Sqlite function in an application and trigger it from another application?

Example:

- I create a trigger which calls MyFunction() after an update
- Application A uses SQLiteFunction.Register to register the function called MyFunction
- Application B makes an update which fires the trigger

When application B makes the update, I receive an error like "Function MyFunction is not defined".
Is there a way to register the function with a "global" scope?

PS: The final purpose is that of simulating events across applications using triggers

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just trying to pass event notifications between multiple applications, SQLite -- or for that matter, any database table -- is the wrong tool for the job.

If the operation is somewhat asynchronous then you might want to use a named [`EventWaitHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx) to notify the other process that you've done something it should be interested in, or if there's data involved, stuff the notification and its data in a [`MessageQueue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.aspx) for the other application to pick up.

Otherwise, you should use a real inter-process communication mechanism like sockets, named pipes, Remoting, WCF, etc.

Comment: @fra: A `MessageQueue` is exactly what you need, then.  They can be made persistent so that even if an app goes down nothing is lost; they can also be enlisted into a transaction if that is relevant.

Comment: Thank you.
We already have a sort of "message dispatcher", anyway I'm afraid that the dispatcher application could crash, losing all events.
That's why I would like to make applications "stateless" using sqlite and saving events on the database; then, we could periodically query the database and check if we lost any events.
The problem is that these applications run on a remote system, so I need many controlling mechanisms.
The Sqlite-trigger solution is more an "academic" solution to understand Sqlite possibilities, it is not really planned to use it on the final system.